# How to merge an array inside another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Im trying to merge or put an Array (called `'$rows_ban'`) inside a sub item of another array (called `'$rows'`) in a final array named `'$rows_final'`.

Im using array_merge but returns null inside `'data'`:

```
{"date":"2018-05-03","hour":"09:12:32","data":[null]}
```

It should return the results in of the second query inside the `'data'`:

```
{"date":"2018-05-03","hour":"09:12:32","data":[{...},{...},{...}]}
```

PHP Script:

```
$rows = array();
$rows_ban = array();
$rows_final= array();

$result1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `id`,`sync_date`,`sync_time` FROM sync_log");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $rows['date']= $r[2];
    $rows['hour']= $r[3];
    $rows['data'][]= null;
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cod, name, total from totals " );

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $rows_ban['cod'] = $r[0];
    $rows_ban['name'] = $r[1];
    $rows_ban['total'] = $r[2];

    $result3 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT *, 1 as Filter from 
        table3 where cod=".$r[0]." order by dates desc");

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        $rows_ban['sub_data'][] = $r;
    }

    $rows_final = array_merge($rows['data'],$rows_ban);
    // here im trying to merge the $rows_ban array inside the 
    $rows['data']
}

echo json_encode($rows_final);
```

Comment: `$rows_final` is the merged data, but you never do anything with it.

Comment: @NigelRen I know is a typing error it should print "$rows_final"

Comment: It looks like you never actually assign anything to $rows['data'], so it would result in null.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to do `$rows['data'] = $rows_ban`?

Comment: that's what im trying in `$rows_final = array_merge($rows['data'],$rows_ban);`

Comment: @GregSchmidt close, but in the next iteration of the query it will replace the previous data.

Comment: Well, the code as shown is going to overwrite `$rows_final` every iteration too...

Comment: Maybe `$rows['data'][] = $rows_ban`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you wanted to accomplish since your description is very poor and hard to understand.

```
$output = [];
$tmpRows = [];

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id`,`sync_date`,`sync_time` FROM sync_log');

if ($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $output['date'] = $tmp[0]['sync_date'];
    $output['time'] = $tmp[0]['sync_time'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT cod, name, total from totals ');

if ($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $tmpRows['cod'] = $tmp[0]['cod'];
    $tmpRows['name'] = $tmp[0]['name'];
    $tmpRows['total'] = $tmp[0]['total'];

    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT *, 1 as Filter from 
        table3 where cod={$tmp[0]['cod']} order by dates desc");

    if ($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $tmpRows['sub_data'] = $tmp[0];
    }

    $output['data'] = $tmpRows;
}


print_r(json_encode($output));
```

Also array_merge doesn't work like you think it does. It returns merged array like it's name states. Regarding to your code, final result would be exactly $rows_ban encoded to json.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php